# configure iptables to redirect traffic to a specific IP address

Tags: 14.04, networking, iptables, firewall, nat

I have just began using iptables. I have a server with a **public** ip address
 ***(A.A.A.A)*** wich is hosting a Virtual Machine ***(B.B.B.B)*** on 
**local** network.

I want to redirect all **inbound** traffic on the port **80** and **443** 
from my public address (A.A.A.A) to my virtual machine (B.B.B.B).

what is the rule to make that working.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is called **DNAT**. And the network architecture you are trying to build is called **DMZ**. See more in Oscar's Anderson's IPTABLES HOWTO. The short answer is :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp \
-d ${MY_EXTERNAL_IP} --dport 80 -j DNAT \
--to-destination ${MY_INTERNAL_HOST_IP}

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp \
    -d ${MY_EXTERNAL_IP} --dport 443 -j DNAT \
    --to-destination ${MY_INTERNAL_HOST_IP}
```

Comment: The answer is incomplete. You need a return path, using either SNAT (preferred) or MASQUERADE in a POSTROUTING step. You also need to be sure that `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` is 1.